# SHould I use cordova.js or phonegap.js JS files in my index.html?

Tags: jquery, cordova, phonegap-build

I am suing the phonegap built in service: 
https://build.phonegap.com

My question is:

1) Do I need to **include phonegap.js or cordova.js** into my index.html file ?
and **where to get these files from** ?

2) Should I inlcude these files if I intend to use "media" object to play sounds ?

regards

Answer (score 1):

You don't include these files at all - they are added at build by the Build service. Well, one is anyway.

You use phonegap.js and you just put a reference to it in your index.html like this:

```
<script src="phonegap.js"></script>
```

It should be the last js file you reference in your header.

That's it! Easy!

Comment: Sorry I dont' understand ! You say do not include that file and then you ask me to include it in header !
And when to get it from ? what version ?

Comment: You don't need the file. Just put the reference. Phonegap Build will put the file in for you.

Comment: @SubjectiveEffect Hi. One question. Why should cordova.js/phonegap.js be put last? I had an issue on android and this fixed it. I mean, why is it important in this case that cordova loads last? Thanks

Comment: @patentul I've no idea. That's what worked though. This may all have changed now though... its 4 years later...

Answer (score 0):

*You should reference cordova.js or phonegap.js in your index.html file.

```
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

Note that this is interchangeable with

```
<script src="phonegap.js"></script>
```

*you should remove the actual files from your site folder before uploading to the phonegap build service as PhoneGap requires a different JavaScript file for each platform and using an incompatible phonegap.js will result in errors when running your application.

for more information please check //
[Getting Started with Build](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/introduction_getting_started.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Build)